# Turning Array of objects into a bag

Tags: kql

I have a dynamic list from a JSON file that I need to convert. Thanks to the setup I will always get the following output format, but I cannot be certain of the order of the list, just the contents.

```
[
  {"#text": "Foo"
   "@Name": "Bar"}
  {"#text": "Woo"
   "@Name": "Tar"}
  {"#text": "Fuu"
   "@Name": "Bear"}
]
```

And I would love to end up with:

`{"Foo": "Bar", "Woo": "Tar", "Fuu": "Bear"}`

I have tried to use mv-expand, however, I am not able to collect the columns as they are called #text and @Name, meaning that they are invalid to use in a query. I am very new to this language and haven't been able to find anything matching my problem.

Comment: It seems you are missing commas in your data sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print obj = dynamic([
  {"#text": "Foo",
   "@Name": "Bar"},
  {"#text": "Woo",
   "@Name": "Tar"},
  {"#text": "Fuu",
   "@Name": "Bear"}
])
| mv-apply obj on (summarize make_bag(pack(tostring(obj['#text']), tostring(obj['@Name']))))
```

| bag_ |
| --- |
| {"Foo":"Bar","Woo":"Tar","Fuu":"Bear"} |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAAysoyswrUchPylKwVUipzEvMzUzWiOZSUKhWUi5JrShRslJQcsvPV9IBCikoOfgl5qaChJwSi5RqdVCVhWMqC8GizK20FMO0VJA6rlhNrhqF3DLdxIKCnEqwk/LzFDSKS3NzE4syq1IVchOzU%20OTEtM1ChKTszVK8otLgG5P1wAqjFYHG68eq6mjoIAqAbYEKAEEAEMSQxLrAAAA)